# GPUImage's GPUImageOpacityFilter not behaving as expected, doesn't change alpha channel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opengl-es, gpuimage

I'm trying to do an `Overlay Blend` of a stock image with the output of the camera feed where the stock image has less than 100% opacity.  I figured I could just place a `GPUImageOpacityFilter` in the filter stack and everything would be fine:

1. GPUImageVideoCamera -> MY_GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter
2. GPUImagePicture -> GPUImageOpacityFilter (Opacity 0.1f) -> MY_GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter
3. MY_GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter -> GPUImageView

But what that resulted in wasn't a 0.1f alpha version of GPUImagePicture blended into the GPUImageVideoCamera, it resulted in kinda softening the colors/contrast of GPUImagePicture and blending that.  So I did some searching and on a suggestion tried getting a UIImage out of the GPUImageOpacity filter using `imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` and sending that into the BlendFilter:

1. GPUImagePicture -> MY_GPUImageOpacityFilter (Opacity 0.1f)
2. **[MY_GPUImageOpacityFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput]**-> MY_alphaedImage
3. GPUImagePicture (MY_alphaedImage) -> MY_GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter
4. GPUImageVideoCamera -> MY_GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter
5. MY_GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter -> GPUImageView

And that worked exactly as I would expect.  So, why do I have to `imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput`, shouldn't that just happen in line?  Here are the code snippits of the two scenarios above:

**first one:**

```
//Create the GPUPicture
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someFile"];
GPUImagePicture *textureImage = [[[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];

//Create the Opacity filter w/0.5 opacity
GPUImageOpacityFilter *opacityFilter = [[[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init] autorelease];
opacityFilter.opacity = 0.5f
[textureImage addTarget:opacityFilter];

//Create the blendFilter
GPUImageFilter *blendFilter = [[[GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter alloc] init] autorelease];

//Point the cameraDevice's output at the blendFilter
[self._videoCameraDevice addTarget:blendFilter];

//Point the opacityFilter's output at the blendFilter
[opacityFilter addTarget:blendFilter];

[textureImage processImage];

//Point the output of the blendFilter at our previewView
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.previewImageView;
[blendFilter addTarget:filterView];
```

**second one:**

```
//Create the GPUPicture
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someFile"];
GPUImagePicture *textureImage = [[[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];

//Create the Opacity filter w/0.5 opacity
GPUImageOpacityFilter *opacityFilter = [[[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init] autorelease];
opacityFilter.opacity = 0.5f
[textureImage addTarget:opacityFilter];

//Process the image so we get a UIImage with 0.5 opacity of the original
[textureImage processImage];
UIImage *processedImage = [opacityFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
GPUImagePicture *processedTextureImage = [[[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:processedImage] autorelease];

//Create the blendFilter
GPUImageFilter *blendFilter = [[[GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter alloc] init] autorelease];

//Point the cameraDevice's output at the blendFilter
[self._videoCameraDevice addTarget:blendFilter];

//Point the opacityFilter's output at the blendFilter
[processedTextureImage addTarget:blendFilter];

[processedTextureImage processImage];

//Point the output of the blendFilter at our previewView
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.previewImageView;
[blendFilter addTarget:filterView];
```

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with the somewhat inconsistent way that I handle premultiplied alpha in input images. I'm not sure that this is being dealt with correctly throughout the input and output pathways. Do you get a better result if you just use a GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter (no GPUImageOpacityFilter) and set the `mix` property to match your desired opacity?

Comment: I don't think `GPUImageDissolveBlendFilter` blends alpha (I tried it in Photoshop), I tried `GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter` though to blend the final output from `GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter` back over the initial output from the camera setting the `mix` property to the desired opacity and it worked like a charm!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you want, you might be able to create a custom blend to do what you want. If you look at the fragment shaders for the various blends, you'll see that they're pretty simple. It wouldn't be that hard to make the dissolve blend respect alpha in the overlay image, for example. I just tried to create these based on Adobe's published blend math, and had a tendency to forget the alpha channel when doing so.