# GPUImageLightenBlendFilter with opacity

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es, gpuimage, core-image

Using `GPUImage` I am trying to replicate Photoshop Lighten Blend Mode with opacity. Unfortunately the alpha channel has no effect using the `GPUImageLightenBlendFilter`.

[image: Photoshop Lighten Blend Mode with opacity]

Brad confirms there might problems with alpha:
[GPUImage's GPUImageOpacityFilter not behaving as expected, doesn't change alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470786/gpuimages-gpuimageopacityfilter-not-behaving-as-expected-doesnt-change-alpha)

I have successfully replicated the PS blending using `CoreImage` which respects the alpha value.

```
CIImage *ciImage1 = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:input1];
CIImage *ciImage2 = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:input2];

// Alpha adjustment for input1
CIFilter *alphaFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
CGFloat rgba[4] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5 };
CIVector *alphaVector = [CIVector vectorWithValues:rgba count:4];
[alphaFilter setValue:alphaVector forKey:@"inputAVector"];
[alphaFilter setValue:ciImage1 forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

// Lighten blend
CIFilter *blendFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILightenBlendMode"];
[blendFilter setValue:alphaFilter.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[blendFilter setValue:ciImage2 forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
```

There are 2 versions of `GPUImage` I have tried (they are adjusting alpha for `input1` using a different method).

```
GPUImagePicture *input1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:input1];
GPUImagePicture *input2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:input2];

// Alpha adjustment for input1
GPUImageOpacityFilter *alphaFilter = [GPUImageOpacityFilter new];
alphaFilter.opacity = 0.5;
[input1 addTarget:alphaFilter];

// Lighten blend
GPUImageLightenBlendFilter *blendFilter = [GPUImageLightenBlendFilter new];
[alphaFilter addTarget:blendFilter];
[input2 addTarget:blendFilter];
```

or:

```
GPUImagePicture *input1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:input1];
GPUImagePicture *input2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:input2];

// Alpha adjustment for input1
GPUImageColorMatrixFilter *alphaFilter = [GPUImageColorMatrixFilter new];
alphaFilter.colorMatrix = (GPUMatrix4x4) {
  { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
  { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
  { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 },
  { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5 }
};
[input1 addTarget:alphaFilter];

// Lighten blend
GPUImageLightenBlendFilter *blendFilter = [GPUImageLightenBlendFilter new];
[alphaFilter addTarget:blendFilter];
[input2 addTarget:blendFilter];
```

Both `GPUImage` implementations return output as if alpha for `input1` was `1.0`.

I have looked at Lighten Blending Mode documentation in different sources on the internet and they all use this formula:

```
max(blend, base)
```

Looking at the shader in implementation of `GPUImageLightenBlendFilter` it also uses the same formula:

```
lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
lowp vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);
gl_FragColor = max(textureColor, textureColor2);
```

However, it seems that Photoshop and `CoreImage` have some extra manipulation with the alpha (probably similar to Gimp: https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/783bbab8a889d4eba80b6a83f2e529937a73a471/app/operations/gimpoperationlightenonlymode.c).

Anyone has ideas how to include the alpha channel in the `GPUImageLightenBlendFilter` formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Shader code the best for my case:

```
lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
lowp vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate2);

textureColor.rgb *= textureColor.a;
textureColor2.rgb *= textureColor2.a;
lowp vec4 textureOut = max(textureColor, textureColor2);
textureOut.rgb /= textureOut.a;

gl_FragColor = textureOut;
```

Found here:
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/pull/1297

Answer (score 1):

Below is shader code for `GPUImageLightenBlendFilter` with opacity and amount.

```
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;
uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2;
uniform float alpha;   // used for opacity....
uniform float amount;  // amount of blend....
varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main ()
{
    // Get samples from both layers
    vec4 dst = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    vec4 src = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, textureCoordinate);

src.a *= alpha;
vec4 colour = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

colour = vec4(max(dst, src).rgb, src.a) * src.a + dst * (1.0 - src.a);
colour = clamp(colour, 0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor.xyz = mix(dst, colour, amount).rgb;
gl_FragColor.w = 1.0;
}
```

Works perfectly for me....